# How to show/plot "matplotlib.lines.Line2D" from numpy array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following array:

```
test = np.array([<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69d76517d0>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69d7649610>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69d7f44b50>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69d7f47610>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69d7f700d0>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69d7f70b50>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69e045cc10>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69e0449b50>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69e043c610>,
   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f69e043e0d0>], dtype=object)
```

wich contains a group of lines that I desire to plot, but I don't know how to show them in a graph using matplotlib. Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: @DYZ I've tried `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(test[0])` (for example) and it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Was there an error message? If so, what did it say?

Comment: @DYZ `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Comment: My apologies. Must be `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`.

Comment: @DYZ it hasn't worked for me too, now it raises the error `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure`. Well, I'm going to try another way. By the way thanks for your helping.